# Rest api, how to add auth bearer token with web service requestor and provider

Tags: php, web-services, authentication, bearer-token

so, i have a problem here. i already make the provider and requestor. it runs okay and success, then i want to make the authentication with bearer token but there is no example of it. i try to search any documentation about it but i cant find any. is anyone know how to do that?
i just have this kind of example about auth using bearer token but i dont know how to do it

this is the example of the auth with bearer token

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Content-Range, Content-Disposition,Content-Description');

//Masukkan file koneksi
include 'koneksi.php';

//Definisikan Token
define('ClientID','01c4bf6ba816ef53c34e057af258f76f');
define('ClientSecret','cda2c99fbf5e19f20d331299c15a4491');
$token=base64_encode(ClientID.":".ClientSecret);
$action=$_REQUEST['act'];
$requestHeaders = apache_request_headers();
$Authorization = trim($requestHeaders['Authorization']);

    if (isset($Authorization)) 
    {
        list($type, $data) = explode(" ", $Authorization, 2);   
        if (strcasecmp($type, "Bearer") == 0) 
        {
            if($data!=$token)
            {
                echo '{"error":"Invalid Token"}';
                exit();
            }
        }else 
        {
            echo '{"error":"Invalid Auth Type"}';
            exit();
        }
    }else 
    {
        echo '{"error":"No Authx - '.$Authorization.'"}';
        exit();
    }
    
//Ambil parameter data JSON untuk pemanggil fungsi dan data parameter
$REQUEST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
if($REQUEST)
{
    $vparam=$REQUEST[data]; 
    $REQUEST[act]($vparam,$con);
}else
{
    $vparam=$_REQUEST[data];
    $act=$_REQUEST[act];
    $act($vparam,$con); 
}

//Fungsi Menampilkan Semua Provinsi
function GetAllProvinsi($vparam,$con)
{
    $sql = 'select * from provinsi';
    $query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    $output[]=$data;
    echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

is anyone know how to do that?

this is my requestor

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $.getJSON("http://localhost/webservice/webprovider.php", function(result){
        console.log(result);
        $.each(result.product,function(i) { 
            document.getElementById("rowProduct").innerHTML +=
            "<tr><td>" + result.product[i].id +
            "</td><td>" + result.product[i].kategori +
            "</td><td>" + result.product[i].nama +
            "</td><td>" + result.product[i].deskripsi +
            "</td><td>" + result.product[i].berat +
            "</td><td>" + result.product[i].harga +
            "</td><td>" + result.product[i].stock +
            "</td><td>" + result.product[i].attribut[0].warna + 
            "</td><td>" + result.product[i].attribut[0].ukuran + 
            "</td><td>" + result.product[i].attribut[0].jenis_bahan + 
            "</td><td>" + result.product[i].attribut[0].motif + 
            "</td><td>" + result.product[i].attribut[0].penutup + 
            "</td></tr>";
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Data Product Wunjoess</h3>
<div id="dataProduct">
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr><th>ID</td>
                <th>Kategori</th>
                <th>Nama</th>
                <th>Deskripsi</th>
                <th>Berat</th>
                <th>Harga</th>
                <th>Stock</th>
                <th>Warna</th>
                <th>Ukuran</th>
                <th>Jenis Bahan</th>
                <th>Motif</th>
                <th>Penutup</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="rowProduct">
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).